# Python getopt behavior

Tags: python, getopt

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import getopt

o, a = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'ab:c:')

print "options: %s" % (o)
print "arguments: %s" % (a)
```

running python:

```
python TestOpt.py a b 10 c 20
```

it prints out like this:

```
options: []
arguments: ['a', 'b', '10', 'c', '20']
```

I don't understand why options is an empty list while arguments looks like options?

Comment: *"Users who are unfamiliar with the C `getopt()` function or who would like to write less code and get better help and error messages should consider using the [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) module instead."*

Comment: Are you familiar with Unix command-line conventions? Options start with a hyphen.

Comment: With hyphen, I see options now but arguments become an empty list. Is that what it's supposed to do?`options: [('-a', ''), ('-b', '10'), ('-c', '20')]
arguments: []`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with:

```
python TestOpt.py -a -b 10 -c 20 foobar
```

Comment: With hyphen I get this: `options: [('-a', ''), ('-b', '10'), ('-c', '20')]
arguments: []` Now argument is empty. Do you know why?

Comment: You should get: ```options: [('-a', ''), ('-b', '10'), ('-c', '20')]
arguments: ['foobar']```

Comment: Which version of Python 2.x are you running?

Comment: Ok now I do. Would you mind telling me why foobar is in the arguments? I was expecting `['', '10', '20', 'foobar']`

Comment: I am running python 2.7.12

Comment: foobar is an argument. The rest are options. See https://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt

Comment: I see. Arguments being no flags. Thank you!